# Error during composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject on Debian

Tags: laravel, installation, xampp, composer-php

I'm on Debian and my PHP version is 7.0.27.

First I began installing Composer using `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` and then `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/composer` (sudo because that's outside of my home directory). Then I typed `composer` and it executed correctly.

Then I launched my XAMPP Apache server and I went to the /opt/lampp/htdocs folder. There I typed the command `sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject` (again, sudo because that's outside of my home directory, but it throwed an alert : "Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details").

But then I got this error :

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

and it printed a bunch of problems.

What did I do wrong?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT1:** I must specify that the `myproject` folder was created nonetheless, but when I got to http://localhost/myproject/public it printed a PHP error :

> Warning: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/public/index.php on line 24
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject/public/index.php on line 24

Comment: you need to install some php packages. just see what errors you get and install those packages like this: sudo aptitude install php7-mcrypt etc mcrypt is one of the packages I think you're missing. A google search would have given you the answer

Comment: Thank you, [here are the errors I got](http://textuploader.com/duixk), which are the extensions I need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel provides a list of what php extensions it requires for each version.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#server-requirements

Those are for the last version. 
According to your error you are missing php-mbstring

Comment: sudo aptitude install php7-mbstring